# Jenkinsfile cannot CD in Windows (bat)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to writting JenkinsFile

I was able to succesfully run `mkdir` and `cd` commands under Executable windows batch commands (Free style project)

But, now I want to write it inside JenkinsFile to use pipeline project

I have the below script which fails to `cd` into an existing directory

```
node('Windows-OS') {
    def workspace = pwd()    
    stage('pre-build') {
        checkout scm
    } 

    stage('build') {
        bat 'echo "Buils starting..."'
        bat 'echo "CD"'
        bat "cd '${workspace}\\CS'"   
        bat 'CD'      
    }
}
```

error: `C:\Source\workspace\Win_Pipeline_Proj>cd 'C:\Source\workspace\Win_Pipeline_Proj\CS' 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I even tried running `bat "cd CS"` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine using multiline batch commands

```
bat '''
    echo "Buils starting..."'
    CD CS
    cd
'''
```